# Добавление и подсчет одинаковых элементов в hashMap java

Tags: java, hashmap

У меня есть `ArrayList` доменов. Мне нужно сделать подсчет повторяющихся элементов из `ArrayList`, и запихнуть их в `HashMap`.
Я вижу это так:

```
//Лист доменов
List<String> listOfEmails = new ArrayList<>();

//Будущая мапа для хранения отсортированных элементов
Map<String, Integer> sortedMap = new HashMap<>();

for (int k = 0; k < listOfEmails.size(); k++) {
    domen = listOfEmails.get(k);

    /*Если ключа с таким доменом не существует,
    то добавляем новый и ставим значение 1 */
    if (sortedMap.get(domen)==null){
        sortedMap.put(domen,1);
    }else{

    //Если существует, то инкрементировать значение на 1
}
```

Как мне сделать метод в `else`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Я дам несколько альтернатив подсчета:

- Примерно как у вас в вопросе

  ```
  List<String> lst = new ArrayList<String>();

  lst.add("Test");
  lst.add("Test");
  lst.add("Hello");
  lst.add("Wat");

  Map<String, Integer> mp = new HashMap<String, Integer>();

  for (String string : lst) {
      // если уже есть ключ, то прибавляем единицу
      if(mp.keySet().contains(string)) {
          mp.put(string, mp.get(string) + 1);
      // Если нет, то кладем ключ и присваиваем значение 1
      } else {
          mp.put(string, 1);
      }
  }

  System.out.println(mp);
  ```

---

- Использовать [Collections.frequency](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#frequency(java.util.Collection,%20java.lang.Object)) - который как раз подсчитывает частоту встречаемого значения в коллекции

  ```
  List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
  Map<String, Integer> mp2 = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
  list.add("aaa");
  list.add("bbb");
  list.add("aaa");

  Set<String> unique = new HashSet<String>(list);
  for (String key : unique) {
      mp2.put(key, Collections.frequency(list, key));
  }

  System.out.println(mp2);
  ```

  output:

  ```
  {aaa=2, bbb=1}
  ```

---

- Java8 и streamAPI

  ```
  List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();        
  list.add("aaa");
  list.add("bbb");
  list.add("aaa");

  Map<String, Long> result =
          list.stream().collect(
                  Collectors.groupingBy(
                          Function.identity(), Collectors.counting()
                  )
          );

  System.out.println(result);
  ```

  output:

  ```
  {aaa=2, bbb=1}
  ```

  Немного про стримы:

  - https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/package-summary.html
  - [Шпаргалка Java программиста (Stream API)](https://habrahabr.ru/company/luxoft/blog/270383/)

Comment: объясните чем отличается код первого примера `if(mp.keySet().contains(string)) {`
от этого `if(mp.contains(string)) {`
зачем там нужен `keySet()`?

Answer (score 1):

Если вы хотите инкрементировать значение в вашей мапе на 1 в блоке `else`, можете написать так:

```
else {
    sortedMap.put(domen, sortedMap.get(domen) + 1);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Вы забыли о наличии тернарных операторов. Данная задача с их помощью решается очень просто:

```
for (int k = 0; k < listOfEmails.size(); k++) {
    String domen = listOfEmails.get(k);
    sortedMap.put(domen, sortedMap.get(domen) == null ? 1 : sortedMap.get(domen) + 1);
}
```